# Zend Framework 1.1 Modules setup

Tags: zend-framework, module, zend-tool

i used `zend_tool` to setup a project then to `create module blog` with index controller etc but i guess the default config setup by zend_tool does not work with modules so i edited it

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectoryControllerName = "controllers"
```

i guess these are required for modules? also i moved the folders, `controllers, models, views` into the `modules/` folder

but i get a blank screen when i try to go to `http://servername` which shld load Default module's index controller and action. even if i try to go `http://servername/nonexistentpage` it also shows a blank screen instead of a 404

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to move `controllers`, `models`, and `views`.
These are directories of the `default` module, which is not placed in `modules` directory (by default).

All you need is:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =
```

If you want to place default `module` in the `modules` too, you have to set up the app like this:

```
; Default Application Resource Namespace
appnamespace = "YourPrefix"

; FrontController Resource Settings
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "modulename"
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

The reason you do not see anything is that the app throws errors, which are not shown due to your configuration. Try these settings:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Ensure you have `SetEnv APPICATION_ENV development` in your `.htaccess`

Upgrade Zend Framework to the newest version. Newest Zend Tool generates /docs directory with `README.txt`, which describes how to set up virtual host.

Hope this helps :)

And…
Welcome to the SO!

Comment: thanks but now i got `Invalid controller specified (index) ` but indexController is generated by Zend_Tool which seems valid

Comment: Zend Tool generates files in standard location, so you don't have to modify the app structure. If you modify it, Zend Tool generates files in wrong location. Take a look at [Quickstart tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html).